# Wordpress API: How do I get the category names by ID in VueJS?

Tags: json, wordpress, api, vue.js

I'm working on a small VueJS app that pulls in a list of blog posts using the Wordpress API. The categories are just IDs in the json, and I'd like to use the actual category names. For the example I'm using https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5&_embed for the json feed. Sample code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/richbachman/oa1L1aqm/

```
var app = new Vue ({
el: "#wp-app",
data: function() {
    return {
        searchQuery: '',
        sources: [
            {
                name: 'TechCrunch',
                url: '//techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5&_embed',
                posts: []
            }
        ]
    }
},

filters: {
    niceDate: function(value) {
        if(!value) return '';
        var date = moment.utc(value);
        return date.format('MMM DD, YYYY');
    }
},

methods: {
    getPosts: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.sources.forEach(function(source, index){
      self.$delete(source, 'posts');
            var searchUrl = self.generateUrl(source);   
            self.$http.get(searchUrl).then(function(response)  {
                self.$set(source, 'posts', response.data);
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('Error');
            })
    });
  },

  generateUrl: function(source) {
    var self = this;
    if(self.searchQuery) {
        return source.url + '&search=' + encodeURI(self.searchQuery);
    } else {
        return source.url;
    }
  }
},

mounted: function(){
    this.$nextTick(function(){
        this.getPosts();
    });
}
});
```

Using the above code, I'm able to pull in an array of category IDs using:

```
{{post.categories}}
```

Just not sure how to translate those IDs to actual category names. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are unable to edit the `endpoint`, you'll need to do an additional API-Request to the `/categories` endpoint. There are multiple ways to do this.

### Request Single Category inside loop

So basically the most obvious thing would it be to loop through all the `categories` and request the data like this: `https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/3457`

But obviously, this is not really good for the performance.

### Request multiple Categories

In order to reduce it to a single request, you can simply add the `ID's` comma separated to the query string.

So like this: `https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/3457,17396,37621928,576601119`

There are plenty of ways to make this happen in code. The easiest one would be to simply loop through your `categories` and create a flatten array with unique values out of it.

Then you could simply convert the array to comma a seperated string by using JavaScripts `join(',')` method and create the `URL` out of it.

In the end, you would need to convert the response `Array` to an object. In this case, you can simply access categories by `ID`.

Here's a working demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/qtejnmym/

I've just created this in the browser, feel free to update it to more modern JS

> Notice: It seems like TechCrunch will not return every category. You can check this by calling this URL: https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?include=3457,17396,37621928,576601119,449557100,20429,449557102,449557028,424613844,449557096,449557086,15986864,449223024,2401
>
> There are 13 `ID's` included as query string, but just 10 get returned.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data that's returned, I noticed that the api is not returning anything other than category ids.

I guessed (and was right) that the endpoint for categories was `/categories`.

Here's a sample route to get one of the categories from the site: https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/25515

I don't recommend looping through the posts and getting the categories one at a time :)

You can hit this route instead with a list of ids: https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?include=25515,20429

Parse through the posts and grab a unique list of categories and make a second call.

Here's a link to the documentation for the categories api for Wordpress: http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/